# How to handle with popup window in Protractor

Tags: jasmine, protractor

Sometimes, when my testing sensor reach alarming level, app immediately overlay browser window with incident window, which i must confirm, and then my tests fail. How can i solve this, without turning off incidents window in app configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Identify or handle javascript popup/alert using protractor in automation.

**Use accept method to press ok/submit button on the displayed popup.**

```
browser.driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
```

**Dismiss javascript popup:**

```
browser.driver.switchTo().alert().dismiss();
```

**Get the text of javascript popup:**

```
browser.driver.switchTo().alert().getText();
```

**Send Keys to javascript popup:**

```
browser.driver.switchTo().alert().sendKeys("Value");
```

**Handling child browser popup in protractor:**
(This code switches into child browser popup)

> Child browser is popup having many web elements. Elements inside the
>   popup can be inspected and elements can be identified by find element
>   and any actions can be performed on those elements.

```
browser.getAllWindowHandles().then(function(handles) {
 var count=handles.length;
 var newWindow = handles[count-1];
 browser.switchTo().window(newWindow);
```

});

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if element is present and if is present to click it, some code similar to this:

```
 static async clickIfPresent(target: ElementFinder) {
    const isPresent = await target.isPresent();
    if (isPresent) {
        return this.click(target);
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: and place it in beforeEach()?